# Show window 2nd+ time with fade-in transition

Tags: winapi, dwm

Say you have a `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` window, and you show it for the first time:

```
::ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
```

The window appears with the expected fade-in animation (testing on Windows 10.0.18363).

If you then hide the window:

```
::ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);
```

and try to re-show it again, with the `SW_SHOW` call above, it will appear instantly, without the fade-in transition.

The question is: **How to make `::ShowWindow()` use the fade-in transition when showing the window for the second time?**

Note that both the first and subsequent `SW_HIDE` calls do use the fade-out transition.

---

There's an unanswered 5-year old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931803/why-does-opening-a-qdialog-the-second-time-cause-it-to-be-shown-immediately-not) that asks essentially the same for QT, but since this is a Win32 problem, not specific to QT, I've decided to re-ask it in more general terms.

Comment: You could use AnimateWindow instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-animatewindow

Comment: @SimonMourier just tried `::AnimateWindow(hwnd, 200, AW_ACTIVATE | AW_BLEND)` - it does produce *an* animation, but a rather weird one, and entirely different from what the system does when showing the window for the first time.

Comment: Looks like what is needed is a way to re-set the "first time" flag of sorts. I did try the `DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED` attribute for `::DwmSetWindowAttribute()` with `disabled:FALSE`, but to no avail.

Comment: The documentation for [ShowWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) points out under which conditions the arguments are ignored. It is quite likely that your first call's `SW_SHOW` argument is simply ignored. You'd have to figure out what value is ultimately passed into the system and replicate that.

Comment: @IInspectable the docs talk about program startup. The window in question is being presented sometime during program execution (think a non-modal About box).

Comment: And yes, I did try the other `SW_SHOW*` flags before posting this question, the results are identical.

Comment: Could you show a mini, complete and reproducible sample and what fade-in animation you expected?

Comment: Wondering if a solution has been found. I'm also trying to resolve this...

Comment: @StefanKoell I ended up just recreating the window.

Comment: Is there a way to do this as of 2022? I can't recreate the window

Comment: Frame animation is enabled when the window transitions from minimized to normal state.  So simply call ShowWindow() twice, first pass SW_MINIMIZE, then pass SW_NORMAL.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Sea Coast of Tibet's comment, I did this for a form in my Delphi app called FormPreview:

```
  FormPreview.Perform(CM_RECREATEWND, 0, 0);
  FormPreview.ShowModal;
```

Fixed the problem for me where I show and re-show forms.

Comment: There are no *"forms"* in the [tag:winapi]. Whatever platform or framework you're using this doesn't help with this specific question.